# Filtering using manytomany field based on logged user

Tags: django

Trying to filter a query based on a check if the user is added to the `ManytoMany` Field.

**Models.py**

```
class Book(models.Model):
    book_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    viewed_by = models.ManyToManyField(User)
```

the **view**

```
def get_new_books(request):
    print(request.user)
    new_books = models.Book.objects.filter(viewed_by__in=request.user)
    context = {
        'new_books': new_books,
    }
    return context
```

it returns the error `'User' object is not iterable`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove `in` in your filter as it awaits to find iterable object.

Try:

```
models.Book.objects.filter(viewed_by=request.user)
```

You can read more about `in` in Django [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#in).